# Online accounts: Failed to get the "token" request: Can not resolve proxy hostname ()

Tags: empathy, shotwell, online-accounts

I had my computer with Ubuntu 12.04 a few months without a network card and now it has a new and functional empathy I try to connect on Facebook or posting photos or import Shotwell right through my contacts I get this error:

Failed to get the "token" request: Can not resolve proxy hostname ()

How do I solve it?

-- Spanish

Tuve Mi computadora con Ubuntu 12.04 Unos Cuantos meses sin tarjeta de red y ahora que tiene una nueva y funcional me intento conectar en empathy o publicar Fotos En Facebook atravez de Shotwell o importar mis contactos Me sale este error:

Error al obtener el «token» solicitado: Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()

¿Como lo Resuelvo?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simply,go to Network settings and turn off your proxy settings to none

Comment: explain more please